# How to display unique records from a has_many through relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unique, distinct, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm wondering what is the best way to display unique records from a has_many, through relationship in Rails3.

I have three models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders
    has_many :products, :through => :orders
end

class Products < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders
    has_many :users, :through => :orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true 
    belongs_to :product, :counter_cache => true 
end
```

Lets say I want to list all the products a customer has ordered on their show page.

They may have ordered some products multiple times, so I'm using counter_cache to display in descending rank order, based on the number of orders.

But, if they have ordered a product multiple times, I need to ensure that each product is only listed once.

```
@products = @user.products.ranked(:limit => 10).uniq!
```

works when there are multiple order records for a product, but generates an error if a product has only been ordered once. (ranked is custom sort function defined elsewhere)

Another alternative is:

```
@products = @user.products.ranked(:limit => 10, :select => "DISTINCT(ID)")
```

I'm not confident that I'm on the right approach here.

Has anyone else tackled this? What issues did you come up against? Where can I find out more about the difference between .unique! and DISTINCT()?

What is the best way to generate a list of unique records through a has_many, through relationship?

Thanks

Answer (score 272, accepted):

Have you tried to specify the :uniq option on the has_many association:

```
has_many :products, :through => :orders, :uniq => true
```

From [the Rails documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many):

> `:uniq`
>
> If true, duplicates will be omitted from the collection. Useful in conjunction with :through.

**UPDATE FOR RAILS 4:**

In Rails 4, `has_many :products, :through => :orders, :uniq => true` is deprecated. Instead, you should now write `has_many :products, -> { distinct }, through: :orders`. See the [distinct section for has_many: :through relationships on the ActiveRecord Associations documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#distinct) for more information.  Thanks to Kurt Mueller for pointing this out in his comment.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I will give this a whirl. Sorry of this is a stupid question, but what is the difference between these two ways of using uniq—in the model association and in the controller. How do they differ in their function?

Comment: The difference is not so much whether you remove duplicates in the model or controller but rather you use the :uniq option on your association (as shown in my answer) or the SQL DISTINCT stmt (e.g. has_many :products, :through => :orders, :select => "DISTINCT products.*). In the first case, ALL records are fetched and rails removes the duplicates for you. In the later case, only non-duplicate records are fetched from the db so it might offer better performance if you have a large result set.

Comment: See that performing a count on the relationship returns the right total, another good reason to prefer a SQL DISTINCT rather than the uniq option by Rails.

EDIT: aha it is the same with SQL DISTINCT ! So for people who wants to count them, just make a to_a before counting.

Comment: In Rails 4, `has_many :products, :through => :orders, :uniq => true` is deprecated. Instead, you should now write `has_many :products, -> { uniq }, through: :orders`.

Comment: Note that -> {uniq} in this sense is just an alias for -> {distinct} http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/uniq It occurs in SQL not ruby

Comment: If you get a conflict with `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY` clauses, you can always use `has_many :products, -> { unscope(:order).distinct }, through: :orders`

Comment: thanks @fagiani and if your model has a json column and you use psql it gets more complicated yet and you have to do something like `has_many :subscribed_locations, -> { unscope(:order).select("DISTINCT ON (locations.id) locations.*") },through: :people_publication_subscription_locations, class_name: 'Location', source: :location` otherwise you get `rails ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: could not identify an equality operator for type json`

Comment: The `-> { distinct }` solution solved the issue but made the query pretty slow. `-> { group(:id) }` has the same effect and it is a x10 faster query.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943957/huge-performance-difference-when-using-group-by-vs-distinct

Answer (score 51):

Note that `uniq: true` has been removed from the valid options for `has_many` as of Rails 4.

In Rails 4 you have to supply a scope to configure this kind of behavior. Scopes can be supplied through lambdas, like so:

```
has_many :products, -> { uniq }, :through => :orders
```

The rails guide covers this and other ways you can use scopes to filter your relation's queries, scroll down to section 4.3.3:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference

Comment: In Rails 5.1, I kept getting `undefined method 'except' for #<Array...` and it was because I used `.uniq` instead of `.distinct`

Answer (score 12):

in rails6 use `-> { distinct }` in scope it will work

```
class Person
  has_many :readings
  has_many :articles, -> { distinct }, through: :readings
end
 
person = Person.create(name: 'Honda')
article   = Article.create(name: 'a1')
person.articles << article
person.articles << article
person.articles.inspect # => [#<Article id: 7, name: "a1">]
Reading.all.inspect     # => [#<Reading id: 16, person_id: 7, article_id: 7>, #<Reading id: 17, person_id: 7, article_id: 7>]
```

Comment: grateful for this solution

Answer (score 6):

On Rails 6 I got this to work perfectly:

```
  has_many :regions, -> { order(:name).distinct }, through: :sites
```

I couldn't get any of the other answers to work.

Comment: Same on rails 5.2+

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68084151/1273077 works with Rails 6

Answer (score 5):

You could use `group_by`.  For example, I have a photo gallery shopping cart for which I want order items to be sorted by which photo (each photo can be ordered multiple times and in different size prints).  This then returns a hash with the product (photo) as the key and each time it was ordered can be listed in context of the photo (or not).  Using this technique, you could actually output an order history for each given product.  Not sure if that's helpful to you in this context, but I found it quite useful.  Here's the code

```
OrdersController#show
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  @order_items_by_photo = @order.order_items.group_by(&:photo)
```

`@order_items_by_photo` then looks something like this:

```
=> {#<Photo id: 128>=>[#<OrderItem id: 2, photo_id: 128>, #<OrderItem id: 19, photo_id: 128>]
```

So you could do something like:

```
@orders_by_product = @user.orders.group_by(&:product)
```

Then when you get this in your view, just loop through something like this:

```
- for product, orders in @user.orders_by_product
  - "#{product.name}: #{orders.size}"
  - for order in orders
    - output_order_details
```

This way you avoid the issue seen when returning only one product, since you always know that it will return a hash with a product as the key and an array of your orders.

It might be overkill for what you're trying to do, but it does give you some nice options (i.e. dates ordered, etc.) to work with in addition to the quantity.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. This may be a little more than I need, but interesting to learn from nonetheless (actually I may use this somewhere else in the app). What are your thoughts on performance for the various approaches mentioned on this page?