# SQL Server: Select only one row of rows that has the same ID on some coulmn

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has 3 columns:
 - ID
 - FROM
 - TO
And i have data like that

```
-----------------------
ID   |   FROM   |   TO
1    |   2      |   1
2    |   5      |   1
3    |   7      |   1
4    |   2      |   1
5    |   2      |   1
6    |   9      |   1
7    |   3      |   1
8    |   4      |   1
9    |   5      |   1
```

I would like to create a query that selects all rows where TO = 1 and i don't want to display rows that was previously retrieved, for example i have multiple rows where FROM = 2 and TO = 1, i just need to retrieve that row only once.

My table doesn't really look like this but i am giving a small example because my aim is to collect all FROM numbers but without any redundancy.

Comment: Do you need to return/display other columns besides FROM and TO?

Comment: Do you need the `ID` column?, if so, which one should you choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use distinct keyword

```
select distinct m.from,m.to from mytable as m;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DISTINCT`

`SELECT DISTINCT from,to FROM yourTable WHERE to = 1`

Answer (score 1):

You just have to group by the columns you want to display:

```
select [from] from mytable group by [from]
```

If you want to see how many froms you have all  you have to do is:

```
select [from], count(*) from mytable group by [from]
```

You could use `distinct` but it would slower than group by but require more memory.

Please read here if you want an explanation on the difference between `group by` and `distinct`:
[Huge performance difference when using group by vs distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943957/huge-performance-difference-when-using-group-by-vs-distinct)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you meant `select distinct [FROM] from TableName where [TO] = 1`

OR

may be you need single row for every distinct [FROM] value for given [TO] ?

```
;with cte as (
    select ID, [FROM], [TO],
        rn = row_number() over (partition by [FROM] order by ID)
    from TableName
    where [TO] = 1
)
select ID, [FROM], [TO]
from cte
where rn=1
```