# Trouble converting SQL query with subselect to Hibernate named query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have two tables and I want to select entries from table A who are referenced in table B using two fields present in both tables.

The two fields used to reference the entries are numeric, so the following query does what I want (but it is slow due to the multiplication and because table B is large).

```
select * from TIBP
where IBP_CODE * 100 + IBP_BASE in
      (select FZGLP_CODE * 100 + FZGLP_BASE from TFZGLP)
```

I've successfully mapped this to the following HQL named query:

```
<query name="findWhereReferencedInZglp">
    select tibp 
    from TibpEntity as tibp
    where tibp.code * 100 + tibp.base in
          (select zglp.code * 100 + zglp.base from ZglpEntity as zglp) 
</query>
```

To improve the speed of the above, I've modified the SQL statement as follows:

```
select * from TIBP as A,
              (select distinct FZGLP_CODE, FZGLP_BASE from TFZGLP) as B
where A.IBP_CODE = B.FZGLP_CODE and A.IBP_BASE = B.FZGLP_BASE
```

Sadly, I've not managed to turn this into a named HQL query that can be parsed. Is this even possible using HQL/Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an inner join; something like the following SQL:

```
select A.*,distinct B.FZGLP_CODE, B.FZGLP_BASE 
from TFZGLP B
inner join TIBP A on A.IBP_CODE = B.FZGLP_CODE
    where A.IBP_BASE = B.FZGLP_BASE
```

You can easily convert this to hibernate.

Comment: My DB chokes on your statement because of the placement of "distinct". It works with the following, but obviously does not return the correct data:

`select A.*, B.FZGLP_CODE, B.FZGLP_BASE 
from TFZGLP B
inner join TIBP A on A.IBP_CODE = B.FZGLP_CODE
    where A.IBP_BASE = B.FZGLP_BASE`

However, I've managed to turn your SQL into something that is both accepted by my DB and returns what I want:

`select A.* from TIBP A
join (select distinct FZGLP_CODE as code, FZGLP_BASE as base from TFZGLP) as B
on A.IBP_CODE = B.CODE
    where A.IBP_BASE = B.BASE`

Comment: <continued>

Sadly, that brings me no further because I still fail to "easily convert this to hibernate".

My attempt so far:
`select bp
 from BpEntity as bp
 join 
 (select distinct zglp.base, zglp.code from ZglpEntity as zglp)
 on zglp.uicLaendercode = bp.uicLaendercode
 where zglp.bpUicCode = bp.bpCode`

It still always fails on the opening bracket of the subselect (which had already been the problem in my original attempt):

`ERROR org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter: line 5:9: unexpected token: (`

Comment: Can you use "group by" instead? Something like 

`select A.*
from TFZGLP B
inner join TIBP A on A.IBP_CODE = B.FZGLP_CODE
    where A.IBP_BASE = B.FZGLP_BASE
        group by B.FZGLP_CODE, B.FZGLP_BASE`

You can find further details about the performance of `distinct` and `group by` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943957/huge-performance-difference-when-using-group-by-vs-distinct)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have been unable to make this work. However I try this, I always receive the following error: DB2 error code -122, see [link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fn122.htm)