# select distinct values of a replaced selected result

Tags: mysql, sql, select, replace, distinct

Good day all.

I'm facing a little problem with a mySql query. let's assume we have a table with a coulmn in which the values are pairs, but unified in the same field, so something like this:

```
id  |  serviceName
----+-------------
1   |  foo - bar
2   |  foo - doo
3   |  foo - tep
4   |  bee - bar
5   |  bee - blo
```

I would like to select distinct the first part of serviceName, in this case foo, bee.

the desired output should be:

```
foo
bee
```

in the resultset.

what I've thought right now is something about making a `SELECT DISTINCT a FROM REPLACE ( (SELECT serviceName as a FROM tableName), ' - ***', '')`

but i'm not really sure if it is possible, and how to make it. I only would like to select the first part of the field, and I would like to take only distinct vlaues of it... it is possible? I need a right direction pointing,, I can make researches by my self.

thanks in advance.

Comment: show your desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you always want to split on a dash `-`, this should work for you.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(serviceName, LOCATE('-', serviceName) - 2) FROM tableName;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0aa47/2)

Comment: this is also a really good way, is the distinct better than the other solution?

Comment: @MatteoBononi'peorthyr' Performance-wise, there isn't much/any noticeable difference. Although I believe that if you get very specific, `DISTINCT` may be _slightly_ faster. That being said, if you want to do something like get the count of how many entries match each first section, then you'll want to use `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

IS this what you are looking at  ?

```
select substring_index(serviceName,'-',1) as `first_part` 
from test
group by `first_part`
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4a21/2)**

Comment: this is really aweesome, thanks, I'm only thinking about performance, is this better than a distinct?

Comment: well both have some advantages and disadvantages you check here but for small data set it does not matter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943957/huge-performance-difference-when-using-group-by-vs-distinct

Comment: thanks a lot, this is the thing i'm searching for, now i'm in difficult on which promote as the answer :/

Comment: You must promote the one you choose and the person who answered first and its Patrick Q