# sql request too long ... How to simplify?

Tags: mysql, sql, nested, long-integer

i would like to reduce the process time of my SQL request (actually it runs 10 minutes ...)
I think the problem come from the nested SQL queries.
(sorry for my english, i'm french student)

```
SELECT DISTINCT `gst.codeAP21`, `gst.email`, `gst.date`, `go.amount` 
FROM globe_statistique 
JOIN globe_customers ON `gst.codeAP21`=`gc.codeAP21` 
JOIN globe_orders ON `gc.ID`=`go.FK_ID_customers` 
WHERE `gst.page` = 'send_order' 
AND `gst.date` = FROM_UNIXTIME(`go.date`,'%%Y-%%m-%%d') 

UNION 

SELECT DISTINCT `gst.codeAP21`, `gst.email`, `gst.date`, '-' 
FROM globe_statistique 
WHERE `gst.page` NOT LIKE 'send_order' "
AND (`gst.codeAP21`,`gst.date`) NOT IN 
            ( SELECT `gst.codeAP21`,`gst.date` FROM globe_statistique 
              WHERE `gst.page`='send_order');
```

Thanks

Comment: Re-write NOT IN as LEFT JOIN. And test switch from NOT LIKE to !=.

Comment: I try to change NOT LIKE to != but it's the same, but i remove the nested query and it work, so the probleme come from the rested query ...
My table globe_statistique  :  56000 rows

Comment: You mean that the first SELECT is the slow one?

Comment: did you try my answer ? Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `gst.codeAP21`, `gst.email`, `gst.date`, `go.amount` 
FROM globe_statistique 
JOIN globe_customers ON `gst.codeAP21`=`gc.codeAP21` 
JOIN globe_orders ON `gc.ID`=`go.FK_ID_customers` 
WHERE `gst.page` = 'send_order' 
AND `gst.date` = FROM_UNIXTIME(`go.date`,'%%Y-%%m-%%d') 

UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT t1.`gst.codeAP21`, t1.`gst.email`, t1.`gst.date`, '-' 
FROM globe_statistique t1 
left join globe_statistique t2 on t1.gst.page =t2.gst.page and t1.gst.date =t2.gst.date and t2.gst.page =send_order
WHERE `gst.page` <> 'send_order' AND t2.gst.date is null
```

But i recomment to rename your column names and remove the dots.

Also use `EXPLAIN` to find out why the query is slow and add the correct index

Comment: HI ! Thanks for the response, but i don't understand the last line, what found
`gst.page` <> 'send_order' ?

Comment: @Gabi sould be !=

Answer (score 0):

try to avoid the use of distinct. To this end, UNION ALL should be used. Group by at the end gives the same result:

```
select codeAP21, email, date, amount 
from ( --> your query without distinct but with UNION ALL <-- ) 
group by codeAP21, email, date, amount
```

see: [Huge performance difference when using group by vs distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943957/huge-performance-difference-when-using-group-by-vs-distinct)

Comment: There's a `UNION` already, so that will be doing an implicit `DISTINCT` too

Comment: you are right. you should also do a union all instead. I'll edit my answer