# (Oracle) SQL: Column must contain a list of values

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to figure out an efficient (Oracle) SQL statement that verifies whether a column contains a specific list of values at least once.

One option would be to filter for that list, output all distinct values and then count them. So, something like this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT columnname
      FROM table
      WHERE columnname in ('a', 'b', 'c')
     ) 
;
```

(And then check whether count(*) returns the number 3)

The problem with this is that the DISTINCT statement looks at the whole table, which is very bad performance-wise. All three values of my list could be at the very beginning, so i don't need to look at the millions of other rows. I only want to know that the column contains 'a', 'b' and 'c'.

Does anyone has an idea to solve this efficiently?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be more efficient to look for each value individually:

```
select (case when exists (select 1 from t where col = 'a') and
                  exists (select 1 from t where col = 'b') and
                  exists (select 1 from t where col = 'c')
             then 1 else 0
        end) as has_all_three_flag
from dual;
```

This will be better particularly with an index on `t(col)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to get rid of distinct, then try the below, Group by has better performance than distinct, [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943957/huge-performance-difference-when-using-group-by-vs-distinct).

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM (
      SELECT columnname
      FROM table
      WHERE columnname in ('a', 'b', 'c')
      GROUP BY columnname
     ) 
;
```

Or you can avoid the usage of subquery by

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT columnname)
      FROM table
      WHERE columnname in ('a', 'b', 'c');
```

Comment: This query still must read all rows from the table, while the Gordon's answer picks at most 3 rows using an index.