# optimizing query by removing distinct key word

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-functions

I am trying to tune the one query to increase the performance of the stored function by removing the distinct keyword.

in the process of query tuning, I came across the query in the stored function where the distinct keyword is using due to that performance is degrading, so I am trying to write the query with same functionality without using a distinct keyword.

Current code with distinct keyword:-

```
select distinct dm.strdatadest 
            from PUBLIC.temp te1
            JOIN PUBLIC.applicationconfiguration AC on AC.intapplicationid = te1.applicationid
            JOIN columnmapping cm on cm.intapplicationid = AC.intapplicationid
            JOIN datamapping dm on lower(dm.strcolumnsource) = lower(cm.strcolumnsource)
            JOIN srctable s on s.applicationid=AC.intapplicationid
            where lower(cm.strtablesource) = lower(s.tablename) and 
            lower(dm.strdatasource) = lower('||quote_literal(rec.status) ||') and lower( dm.strcolumndest ) LIKE ''strstatus'' and te1.applicationid='||quote_literal(rec.applicationid);
```

Trying code by removing distinct keyword:-

```
select  dm.strdatadest
from PUBLIC.temp te, 
PUBLIC.applicationconfiguration AC,
            PUBLIC.columnmapping cm,
            PUBLIC.datamapping dm
            where AC.intapplicationid = te.applicationid and cm.intapplicationid = AC.intapplicationid and lower(dm.strcolumnsource) = lower(cm.strcolumnsource)
            and lower(cm.strtablesource) = lower(s.tablename) and 
            lower(dm.strdatasource) = lower('||quote_literal(rec.priority) ||') and lower( dm.strcolumndest ) LIKE ''strpriority'' and te1.applicationid='||quote_literal(rec.applicationid)
            GROUP BY dm.strdatadest;
```

i required some sujjestion who to tune query by removing distinct keyword

Comment: GROUP BY instead of SELECT DISTINCT? What do the queries' execution plans say?

Comment: BTW, you should keep the explicit `JOIN` syntax anyway.

Comment: changing a distinct clause with an group by seems not a good idea ..  in the better case you have the same performance  . ..

Comment: I'm afraid both solutions will perform about the same.

Comment: if you need  better performance try improve your indexing

Comment: Your probably is probably not the `select distinct` but instead the `join` conditions that use functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two points about your query that should be mentioned

1. implicit join vs explicit join which approximately has the same performance.

> people often ask if there is a performance difference between implicit and explicit joins. The answer is: “Usually not”

2. distinct vs group by which **distinct** is optimum for memory usage and **group by** is optimum for speed so the latter outperforms the former but requires a large amount of memory if needed.

> The distinct approach is executed like:
>
> - Copy all business_key values to a temporary table
> - Sort the temporary table
> - Scan the temporary table, returning each item that is different from the one before it
>
> The group by could be executed like:
>
> - Scan the full table, storing each value of business key in a hashtable
> - Return the keys of the hashtable

An astute explanation on the links below.

[implicit join vs explicit join](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgressql-implicit-vs-explicit-joins/)

[distinct vs group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943957/huge-performance-difference-when-using-group-by-vs-distinct)