# Better way to find unique record in has_many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my rails app, a user can go along to events -

user.rb

```
has_many :attendances
has_many :events, through: :attendances
```

event.rb

```
has_many :attendances
has_many :users, through: :attendances
```

... with an attendance table which is made up of event_id, user_id and some other bits and pieces -

attendance.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :writers_event
```

When looking for a particular attendance I find myself using .where ... .first  - e.g.

```
attendance = Attendance.where(user_id: @user.id, event_id: this_event_id).first
```

And it strikes me that I missed the class where we talked about using something like `find_by` in this type of situation - in other words, where you are confident that you are looking for something unique. It might not matter, but searching for a collection then taking the first object from it feels wasteful and wrong.

Is there a better way?

I had a look around, and this was closest, but does not (I don't think) really cover it. [How to display unique records from a has_many through relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846638/how-to-display-unique-records-from-a-has-many-through-relationship)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use find_by for this:

```
attendance = Attendance.find_by(user_id: @user.id, event_id: this_event_id)
```

Although behind the scenes, it is doing a look-up and taking the first.

However, you can get a bit more help from rails here:

```
current_user.attendances.find_by(event_id: this_event_id)
```

Comment: Obviously you can do the same for the event: ```my_cool_event.attendances.find_by(user_id: @user.id)```

Answer (score 5):

It's actually pretty straightforward:

```
attendance = Attendance.find_by(user_id: @user.id, event_id: this_event_id)
```

You just pass the same conditions to `find_by`, and it returns you the first record.

There is one catch though. By using `find_by`, you will get nil, if nothing is found. If you need to get an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` raised, if nothing is found, you can use `find_by!`.

Comment: The find_by behaviour regarding nils and exceptions is very important to remember, as it can bite.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
Attendance.find_by_user_and_event(@user.id, this_event_id)
```

If the record not found then it return `nil`. If you want to raise the exception

```
Attendance.find_by_user_and_event!(@user.id, this_event_id)
```

Comment: According to Upgrading to Rails 4.0 `All dynamic methods except for find_by_... and find_by_...! are deprecated`

Comment: Vote up, if you like my answer ;)